# Pin to Taskbar Menu is Missing for all programs

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I had a new problem after i had finished clearing the registy with an app. When i want to add Chrome and other programs to taskbar, there's no "Pin to Taskbar Menu" in my options. I tried to drag the shortcut directly into the taskbar, but it can't solve my problem. How do i solve this problem? I use windows 7 64 bit

[image]

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/127968-pin-taskbar-pin-start-menu-missing-context-menu-fix.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i got the problem solver from a windows user forum. The problem is getting away by undoing the removing arrow in the desktop shortcuts.